# from sklearn.metrics can't import PredictionErrorDisplay

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have scikit-learn 1.3.2 installed, and I try to import PredictionErrorDisplay, but get an error that I'm not able to resolve:

```
from sklearn.metrics import PredictionErrorDisplay
```

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'PredictionErrorDisplay' from 'sklearn.metrics'
```

Other functions have been running fine.

This is a relatively fresh PC and I haven't installed many packages, so I don't think it's dependency hell.

Comment: Do you have `scipy` installed as well?

Comment: Just to be sure, can you post your results if you just run: `import sklearn` and `sklearn.__version__`

Comment: `scipy==1.9.1` and `sklearn.__version__ == 1.1.2`

Answer (score 1):

`PredictionErrorDisplay` is only available from sklearn version `1.2` (see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.PredictionErrorDisplay.html)

As you state in the comments, only version `1.1.2` is recognized. Since you claim to have `1.3.2` installed, I suspect that you are in the wrong environment.

Comment: Nice and detailed answer!